# Getting Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-developers-console

Trying to follow https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

I got it to work against a google workspace (G-Suite), but then after some calls while playing around with different calls to the **google drive API** I started receiving an error message:

The API returned an error:

> Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

This message suggests that I am having some quota issue. However I made only ~50 calls to the API, hours of work against https://console.cloud.google.com/ and https://console.developers.google.com/ produced no new insights. The quota is 10K calls, so it cant me that I exceeded it with just 50 calls...

None of the Stack Overflow responses I saw related to this seem to apply or be up to date.

Unfortunately this error is missing from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors.

Answer (score 0):

After a day's work I realised that this cryptic response is sent when locally in my code the auth key provided to **google.drive()** API is undefined.

Seems like this cryptic response is used as a "generic error message" by the google API.

---

Below is one example resulting in this error but there are infinity many others - any code that will fail to set the auth during the call to **google.drive()** API will produce the same outcome.

This example code was provided by google and it does work properly.

```
google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
```

The reason it works is that it translates (expands) to:

```
google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: auth});
```

(This expansion is done implicitly by Nodejs)

Using the following code will **produce the error**:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3'});
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
 if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
});
```

Using the following code will not produce the error:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
   if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
});
```

Using the following code will also not produce the error (as it explicitly expands to be the same as the previous one):

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: auth});
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
   if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
});
```

Using the following code will **produce the error** (which was my bad doing):

```
var myAuth = auth;
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', myAuth});
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
   if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
});
```

Using the following code will fix that error:

```
var myAuth = auth;
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: myAuth});
drive.files.list({}, (err, res) => {
   if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: it's because you named your variable myAuth instead of auth